# Render object value filtered against another array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 2 arrays:

```
borders=[US, UK, CAN] 
list=[{country:United States, code:US}, {country:United Kingdom, code:UK}
```

I want to render `list.country` if `list.code` is in borders. I have tried chaining `.map()` and `.filter()`  and also reduce(I don't think correctly) but have not been able to achieve the desired behavior.

What would be the best way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You could [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the list based on whether borders [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) it.

`list.filter(obj => borders.includes(obj['code']))`

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be doing something like that:

```
listFiltered() {
    return list
        .filter(({code}) =>
            borders.includes(code)
        )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given these arrays:

```
borders=['US', 'UK', 'CAN']
list=[{country:'United States', code:'US'}, {country:'United Kingdom', code:'UK'}]
```

I you prefer not to use arrow functions in these cases (like me):

```
list.filter(function(element){ return borders.includes(element.code) })
```

That will filter the elements in the list. To get only the country just append .map() at the end, returning just the element.country :

```
list.filter(function(element){ return borders.includes(element.code) }).map(function(element){ return element.country })
```

With arrow functions:

```
list.filter((element) => borders.includes(element.code)).map((element) => element.country )
```